# Click Listener on the Whole Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I've an activity and inside it a list fragment. In case I receive no elements for the list i'd like to add an onclick listener on the whole layout to retry the request.
Activity layout **relative_browse**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative_browse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then inside the onCreateView of the fragment i inflate **fragment_list_categoriers.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_list_categories"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/gray"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to add the onclick listener on the empty list inside onActivityCreated, but it doesn't work:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View view  = container.findViewById(R.id.fragment_list_categories);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.w("DEBUG", "Click!");
        }
    });

}
```

In particular I've no "Click" log, except for a tiny border of the screen on the left (it's like if the fragment_list_categories cover all the screen except some pixels).
What's the right way to do this?

EDIT: here my **onCreateView** and onClick method

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.inflater = inflater;

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_categories,
            container, false);

    this.container = (ViewGroup) view;

    view.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "Click!");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that pops out at me is that the `ListView` is taking up all the space.

Since you have its height set to `match_parent`, it will always occupy the entire parent's space. If the list is empty, this is probably not the desired behavior.

ListViews are sometimes weird about propagating clicks through to their parent views. When you click it, it's probably just dead-ending there instead of going up the chain. That would explain why you can get the clicks on the "border"; it's just the parent view's padding.

You may want to consider changing the `ListView` height to `wrap_content`. That way if it's empty, it won't take up space and you can get your clicks.

You may also want to try to *detect* if it's actually empty. If you have a couple entries that don't take up the full height of the parent, what is the expected behavior if the user clicks in the "empty" area? If that should trigger the retry as well, that's fine. If not, you need to enable/disable clicking based on that.

Comment: You're right, ListView is weird in propagating click event. I changed height to wrap_content and it seems to work fine, attaching onclick to  root relative. If the list is empty I don't want the refresh behaviour, so I'll manage to remove the listener.

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing you should do is in the onCreateView method instantiate your RelativeLayout as

```
View view = inflater.inflate("Your fragment layout", null);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewByID("your relative layout's ID");
rl.setOnClickListener(this);
return view;
```

Then implement the OnClickListener and override the onClick method as,

```
@override
public void onClick(View v){
   Log.d("Relative LAyout", String.valueOf(v));
}
```

In case you have already done the above then please post your onCreateView code.

Comment: I've posted the method in the edit. The problem could be that I've a ListFragment and not a simple fragment?

Comment: I dont think that should be a problem. What was the output now? And did you try setting the height of the list to wrap_content as Geobits suggested. Also, try setting the background of RelativeLayout and ListView to different colors. This will help you see what area and how much area they take while running. I do this to debug.